# Show that $\sigma_{X+Y} \leq \sigma_X + \sigma_Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Show that $\sigma_{X+Y} \leq \sigma_X + \sigma_Y$

I tried using the formula $Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2\sigma_{XY}$ and also the fact that the correlation coefficient, defined as $\sigma_{X,Y} = \sigma_{XY} /\sigma_X \sigma_Y \leq 1$. However, I can't seem to come to the correct answer. Could anyone please help?

Comment: The variance of $X+Y$ is _not_ the sum of the variances of $X$ and $Y$ unless $X$ and $Y$ are _uncorrelated_ random variables.  But the maximum value of the variance of $X+Y$ occurs when the correlation coefficient equals $1$ and it is given by $$\sigma_{X+Y}^2 = \sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2+2\sigma_X\sigma_Y.$$

Comment: @DilipSarwate Sorry, you are right indeed about that. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @DilipSarwate But how exactly would that prove the inequality that I need?

Comment: $a^2+b^2+2ab = (a+b)^2$ showing that $\sigma_{X+Y}^2\leq (\sigma_X+\sigma_Y)^2$. Taking square roots at this point might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take square roots of $\sigma_{X+Y}^2=\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2+2\sigma_{XY}\le\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2+2\sigma_X\sigma_Y=(\sigma_X+\sigma_Y)^2$ on both sides.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Things are always obvious when you see the solution, but I just couldn't figure this one out. Thanks again :D.